# Agregar un error a la errors bag de laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, validación, laravel-blade

Ante todo saludos. Necesito que las siguientes líneas de códigos en vez de redireccionarme a una vista y mostrar un mensaje de error, me envie el error a la Errors Bag de laravel para poder capturarlo desde la vista.Tengo dudas al respecto y quisiera saber ***cómo enviar el error de este método a la errors bag de laravel 5.5.***
***   ModeloController***

```php
public function store(ModeloRequest $request)
$aux=$request['carro_id'];//guarda el valor que se guarda en la columna de la llave foranea
        $modelo = Modelo::where('carro_id', $aux)->get();//busca los modelos de carro que tengan el carro.id del nuevo que se va a agregar
        if($modelo){//si es distinto de vacio
            foreach($modelo  as $m){
                if($m->numero == $request->numero){//con encontrar una coincidencia entre el nuevo numero y uno ya existente, retorna el error
                    return redirect()->route('modelos')->with('danger_msg', '¡ATENCION El modelo ya está guardado!');
                }
            }
Modelo::create([
    'numero' => $request['numero'],
    'descripcion' => $request['descripcion'],
    'carro_id'=>$request['carro_id'],
]);
return redirect()-route('modelos')->with('success_msg', 'Modelo agregado');
        }
```

***ModeloRequest***

```
public function rules(){
return [
     'numero' => 'required|string|alpha|max:8',
    'descripcion' => 'required|string|paragraph|max:255',
    'carro_id'=>'required|numeric|exist:carros,id'
];}
```

***PD*** busqué en la documentación oficial, en las validaciones y no veo como adaptar lo que alli explican a mi método.

Comment: Esto está dentro de un controlador? Tenés un `Validator` en algún lado? Eso que estás haciendo es una validación. Deberías aplicar esa lógica al `Validator` o a un [`form request`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation). Publicá el resto del código, porque desde un `Validator` se puede obtener el message bag actual.

Comment: @azeós si, esta dentro del  controlador en la funcion update

Comment: `Modelo::where('carro_id', $request['carro_id'])->where('numero', $request->numero)->exists()` Eso no sería básicamente lo que estás validando? Que NO puede haber un `Modelo` con ese `$request->carro_id` y ese `$request->numero`. Eso lo podes validar con un [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique), lee la parte de "Adding Additional Where Clauses". El punto es que te conviene usar un `Validator` ya sea en el controlador o un `form request` como te puse en el comentario anterior. Publicá el código del controlador, confirmá que eso lo que querés validar y lo vemos.

Comment: @azeós tratare de explicarte con palabras para ver si logras entender lo que quiero, de todas formas pondré el codigo q me pides.

Comment: @azeós lo que pasa es que ese Modelo se relaciona de 1 a M con Carro, ahora al agregar un modelo, por supuesto tiene id de tipo unique, tiene numero, descripcion y la llave foranea carro_id, pero el caso de numero no puedo ponerlo unique porque en la tabla este valor puede repetirse siempre que no sea en el mismo carro_id, o sea el carro_id se repite pero dentro de esas repeticiones de ese carro_id en especifico el valor numero debe ser unico, para otro carro_id puede darse el caso q se repita el numero y es valido. Dime si logras entenderme? Lo ideal seria llevarlo al form request

Comment: @azeós lo que quiero es lograr enviar el error con su valor y el mensaje, para despues en la vista(es un modal) resaltar el campo erroneo y mostrar el mensaje, como mismo se trabaja con el form request que es la forma de trabajo q estoy siguiendo, aunque no hay problemas si se hace con el Validator.  Aclarar que anteriormente te puse que ese codigo era para el Update, tambien esta en el Store que es el codigo q se muestra arriba

Comment: Entiendo lo que me decís, y es justamente lo que te estoy planteando. Tu validación *unique* no es de una sola condición, sino de 2: ese *carro_id* con ese *numero* no puede estar duplicado. Por eso te remarqué que revises la parte de "Adding Additional Where Clauses". Publicá tu `form request` y vemos como agregar ahí la validación. Entiendo que tu pregunta apunta directamente a como poner el error en el message bag, pero eso debería manejarse automáticamente desde la validación. Por otro lado, tenés definida en la base de datos que esa relación es *unique*?

Comment: @azeós ya puse el form request, es muy básico. Ya vi en la doc lo q me dijiste y mas o menos tengo una idea pero no estoy seguro. La pregunta sobre si la relación en la bd es unica,es que no lo tengo definido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizá el form request para agregar tu validación:

**ModeloRequest:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ModeloRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'numero'      => 'required|string|alpha|max:8',
            'descripcion' => 'required|string|paragraph|max:255',
            'carro_id'    => [
                'required',
                'numeric',
                'exists:carros,id',
                Rule::unique('tabla')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('numero', $this->input('numero');
                }),
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'carro_id.unique' => '¡ATENCION El modelo ya está guardado!',
        ];
    }
}
```

Usé la regla [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) con un `where`. Eso chequea que el campo `carro_id` junto con el `numero` no se repitan en la *tabla* (reemplazá "tabla" por la tabla donde se están guardando esos campos).

Dentro del método [`messages()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages) podes personalizar los mensajes de error para cada tipo de validación.

Además deberías establecer en tu archivo de migración una clave [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#indexes) entre esas 2 columnas:

**Archivo de migración:**

```
...
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->unique(['numero', 'carro_id']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, @azeós probaré y te cuento los resultados.